# Could login with GitHub be added?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, openid, github

This question seems to be asked already some years ago: *[Login with GitHub?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251670/login-with-github)*

Then it was said the option is not important, no OpenID  in GitHub, etc.

However now, with the end of OpenID support, it would be extremely convenient for many users of Stack Overflow particularly.

Comment: Afaik Data SE can login with github.

Comment: There's a chance Microsoft may merge GitHub's login system with Microsoft accounts. Let's hold off on this until we get a statement regarding what they intend to do with it. (They did the same thing with Skype accounts.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog in my opinion github login works is different technically from microsoft and no one in sane mind will try to perform the trick they've done with skype accounts. With skype this was not really merge but they simply made millions of people to create or bind microsoft login to skype account. With Github such approach will lead to zounds of broken web-applications which use current github login system... So I hope this nightmare won't come to us :)

Answer (score 9):

It seems [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), answer from Geoff Dalgas:

> The GitHub PR was finally approved and merged: 
>   https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about direct sign-in with GitHub, but I know that Ask Ubuntu uses [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) of Launchpad, so it is possible to use a convenient chain from GitHub to Launchpad, then log in to Ask Ubuntu.